# what is equivalent of Postgresql to dbms_stats.gather_table_stats in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, performance, optimization

I have some question about Postgres, I have used dbms_stats.gather_table_stats for performance optimization in Oracle. I would like to switch our database from Oracle to Postgres, therefore, I want to achieve same feature on Postgres also. I searched internet whether there is some equivalent feature existing in Postgres with dbms_stats.gather_table_stats in Oracle. The only I found was EXPLAIN, VACUUM something like that. I think these are already existing in Oracle with same name. but I can't find proper ones for dbms_stats.gather_table_stats. I am spedning a lot time on it, if you guys have some advice, could I get some?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html

Answer (score 2):

The `GATHER_TABLE_STATS` procedure of `DBMS_STATS` package collects statistics of the specified table in Oracle.

In Postgres, we use ANALYZE for the same purpose.

> [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html) collects statistics about the contents of tables in the database, and stores the results in the pg_statistic system catalog. Subsequently, the query planner uses these statistics to help determine the most efficient execution plans for queries.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to do something with ANALYZE and then I wanted to check the result of it, so I tried looking into db_statistic table but it was not accessible. According to db administrator, I can see pg_stats which shows the only details to the user specific tables instead of pg_statistics. My question is when executing 'ANALYZE' without parameters, it shows some warning like below.

Comment: WARNING:  skipping "pg_authid" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_database" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_db_role_setting" --- only superuser can analyze it
.......

It looks like that I can't analyze some system level tables with my user account. Is it right?
Actually, my second question is that how I can exactly check whether execution of 'ANALYZE' is performed sucessfully or not. When executing 'ANALYZE', I got following like below.

Comment: WARNING:  skipping "pg_authid" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_database" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_db_role_setting" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_tablespace" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_pltemplate" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_auth_members" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_shdepend" --- only superuser can analyze it

Comment: WARNING:  skipping "pg_shdescription" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_replication_origin" --- only superuser can analyze it
WARNING:  skipping "pg_shseclabel" --- only superuser can analyze it
Query OK, 0 rows affected (execution time: 702 ms; total time: 702 ms)

Is there any way I can check the time of pg_stats updated?

Comment: analyze emp;  -- analyze <table_name>;